# dynamic texture compression

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Is dynamic texture compression possible in iPhone? (3G or 3GS?)
I create a UIImage dynamically each time the app runs. Can I dynamically generate a PVRTC file from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking strictly about PVRTC, I'm afraid not; ImgTec doesn't give out the source code for their compressor. To add to the problem, PVRTC is a fairly memory-intensive algorithm and would likely be beyond the limits of even a 3GS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not.  As long as you don't mind the fact that the compression will be REALLY slow (Perhaps it could be done in a background thread).

The implementation details can be found in [this paper.](http://web.onetel.net.uk/~simonnihal/assorted3d/fenney03texcomp.pdf).